# Access function arguments dynamically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What we want is to convert function parameters to Dictionary and save in other Dictionary.

Dictionary would look like this:

```
typealias FunctionName = String
typealias ArgumentName = String
typealias ArgumentValue = Any

var parameters: [FunctionName: [ArgumentName: ArgumentValue]] = [:]
```

Every function has different sign. It may look like this.

```
func functionA(arg1:String, arg2:Int) {
    //Convert arg1 & arg2 in dictionary
    //Save that dictionary in parameters Dictionary
    //.....
}

func functionB(arg1:String, arg2:Int, arg3:String, arg4:[Double]) {
    //Convert arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 in dictionary
    //Save that dictionary in parameters Dictionary
    //.....
}
```

One solution is to create dictionary statically like this:

```
let args:[ArgumentName: ArgumentValue] = ["arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2]
let args:[ArgumentName: ArgumentValue] = ["arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2, "arg3": arg3, "arg4": arg4]
```

But we have to write this in every function and we also have to maintain it when function sign change. Thats why we want to make it dynamic.

We can get Function Name as string by using #function. But how to get function arguments name and value as dictionary OR array of key-pair OR array of tuple.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica For log and & testing purpose. In short I want to save function arguments to use at later stage.

Comment: If it's for testing, you're probably testing it wrong. This kind of problem is usually solved with "aspect oriented programming" , though I've never seen that done in Swift.

Comment: If your goal is to exercise the reflection, then you are up for disappointment: reflection is not Swift's strong side. However depending on your actual goal, there are ways to solve this problem in Swift-y ways, and quite elegantly.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yes that can be a case. Let me explain my situation. I want to test function A. A calls function X & Y (X and Y are mock functions). I want to test what argument function A pass to X & Y. What can be more better approach to test this scenario?

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks for the input. Would you show me any direction for swift-y ways?

Comment: @CRDave I usually create my mocks by creating structs that conform to the right protocol, who have a series of closure properties, one per function they implement. They implement the protocol functions by calling the associated closure. From there, I can just instantiate a mock object per test, whose closures contain whatever assertions I need

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Just to clarify what I understand. Suppose we have a protocol with 3 function. So our mock struct will have 3 mock function and 3 closure. Every time a function is called it will call relevant closure. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @CRDave Yep, and you inject that mock into your unit-under-test, and have it call those closures (indirectly, via the protocol), which lead to your assertions getting called

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That is nice alternative. But my original problem remain same. Difference is instead of saving detail in some array now I am passing all detail in some closure. If I have n number of  function then I need n number of closures. And if function sign change I have to make change in closure also. But still I will explore this closure idea more and try to make it more simple if possible. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @CRDave Yes, if the function signature changes, you have to update your tests, *that's the whole point*. If you tests automatically updated to reflect your production code, then they're not tests, they're just useless duplicate code that feeds you superficial green benchmarks.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I don't think that is the case. Saving parameters in the Array (or passing them in closures in your logic) is different from actual test code. Parameter saved in array doesn't mean test is passed. We still have to write test condition to check value of that saved parameters. I want to make parameter saving/ passing logic free from boil-plating code not the Assert code.

Comment: @CRDave What array are you talking about, exactly? Could you show me an example of what your function, call site and test code look like (edit it into your question body)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Array which I have mention in my original question with name "parameters". I have also gave two sample function (Mock implementation of protocol). I still haven't write test case for this scenario but it will query "parameters" array and assert if value not found as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221052/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-crdave).